# Visual studio prevents me from having access to the designer, but it works

Tags: c#, visual-studio, designer

I'm designing a c# .Net framework Winforms application, and I just added some strings, images in a ressource file, and I just redirected some Forms resources from the resource file, and it works (Images shows, strings works) when I generate but Visual Studio won't let me access the designer. And when I ignore the "errors" don't show up in the designer. Any tips?

[image: Designer's message]

[image: Lists of "messages"]
[image: The designer's code for one of the "message"]

Comment: I think there is buggy situation about visual studio. Did you try re-open it ?

Comment: Apparently... You were right, I had just to restart it and it work again. Well thanks you